# Any handler for events when __doPostBack starts and finish Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my case ASP.NET controls are posting back to server and some are with UpdatePanel requests. I need to show **Loading...**  box when `__doPostBack` is being called. I went through ScriptResources javascripts to find any event but couldn't.

Is there any way by which I can get the callback when `__doPostBack` is in progress, started or completed?

Comment: try `UpdateProgress` control

Comment: At some places its not an update panel, but a new windows opening after PostBack. So it could be best to have some events to handle all cases.